# Opencart adding qty to option does not reflect in main

Tags: opencart

I have added a product say product x which I have added qty 0

I have created variations red,green and blue and added 30 qty for each

But when I see it then on shop then it shows out of stock but actually I have qty 90 in stock

How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control inventory exclusively via options you can set your main product **Quantity** in the **Data** tab to something arbitrary (100 for example) and then set **Subtract Stock** to **No**.

Otherwise you need to set the **Quantity** in the **Data** tab to be in sync with your options and set **Subtract Stock** to **Yes**.

[image]